# wrong loop is getting executed in case of valid user

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, response

I have an activity which validates a user by checking the credentials from the server.
Here is my code.

PaymentActivity.java

```
package com.example.androidphpmy;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PaymentActivity extends Activity {
  Button b;
  EditText et,pass;
  TextView tv;
  HttpPost httppost;
  StringBuffer buffer;
  HttpResponse response;
  HttpClient httpclient;
  List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
  ProgressDialog dialog = null;

  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_payment);

      b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);  
      et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.accountno);
      pass= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
      tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);

      b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {

          dialog = ProgressDialog.show(PaymentActivity.this, "", 
            "Validating user...", true);
          new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
            payment();                        
            }
            }).start();               
          }
          });
    }

  void payment(){
    try{            

      httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
      httppost= new 
        HttpPost("http://tanushreedutta.site40.net/payment_new/check.php");
      //add your data
      nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
      // Always use the same variable name for posting i.e the android side variable name and
      php side variable name should be similar,    
          nameValuePairs.add(new           
              BasicNameValuePair("accno",et.getText().toString().trim())); 
      // $Edittext_value = $_POST['Edittext_value'];
      nameValuePairs.add(new 
          BasicNameValuePair("bpassword",pass.getText().toString().trim())); 
      httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
      //Execute HTTP Post Request
      response=httpclient.execute(httppost);
      // edited by James from coderzheaven.. from here....
      ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new      
        BasicResponseHandler();
      final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
      System.out.println("Response : " + response); 
      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
          tv.setText("Response from PHP : " + response);
          dialog.dismiss();
          }
          });

      if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("User Found")){
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(PaymentActivity.this,"Payment Successful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            });

        startActivity(new Intent(PaymentActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
      }
      else{
        showAlert();                
      }

    }catch(Exception e){
      dialog.dismiss();
      System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
    }
  }
  public void showAlert(){
    PaymentActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(PaymentActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Payment Error.");
        builder.setMessage("User not Found.")  
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
          }
          });                     
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();               
        }
        });
  }
}
```

Response generating php file

```
<?php
$hostname_localhost ="url";
$database_localhost ="databasename";
$username_localhost ="myusername";
$password_localhost ="xxxx";
$localhost = mysql_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost)
 or
trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);

mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);

$accno = $_POST['accno'];
$bpassword = $_POST['bpassword'];
$query_search = "select * from details where accno = '".$accno."' AND bpassword =      
'".$bpassword. "'";
$query_exec = mysql_query($query_search) or die(mysql_error());
$rows = mysql_num_rows($query_exec);
//echo $rows;
if($rows == 0) { 
echo "No Such User Found"; 
}
else  {
echo "User Found"; 
}

?>
```

Now the problem is whenever I enter account no and password in response text it gives me correct output but in any of the cases (valid or invalid user) it executes "else" statement i.e executes showAlert() method. Is there any problem with my code.Any suggestion or advice will be highly appreciated. Thank you all in advance !

Comment: Please format your code properly. It is impossible to tell what is going on with the indentation like this.

Comment: What does your String response print to console?

Comment: It looks like the issue here may be with the service call to `http://tanushreedutta.site40.net/payment_new/check.php`, so we'd need to know what value it's returning.

Comment: Did you notice that you have an instance variable called `response` and also a local variable with the same name? I'd check if you might be using the wrong one at some point.

Comment: What does your `response` look like?

Comment: You should really be using some kind of naming convention that distinguishes instance variables from local variables. For example, you can have a rule that all instance variables start with "\_", or "m\_". Name clashes can be very nasty and hard to debug, so do everything you can to avoid them.

Comment: @Nate C-K - it is giving me correct response from the server and shows a text like: Response from PHP : User Found/ No Such User Found depending upon a valid or invalid user but if its a valid user then it must execute if statement and show a toast but in both the cases it executes showAlert() method.

Comment: @user3352495- Response text is sumthing like dis. Response from PHP : User Found/ No Such User Found depending upon a valid or invalid user.

Comment: Are you sure the string is **exactly** what you expect, e.g. no extra spaces anywhere or anything like that? When dealing with strings from input, it's usually advisable to call trim() on them to avoid that kind of problem.

Comment: @Nate C-K - I want to send you the screenshots of my emulator screen. How is dat possible ?

Comment: @user3399423: The question editor has a button to upload an image and include it with your question text.

Comment: Also, please use PDO or mysqli instead of the "mysql" extension in your PHP code. The mysql extension is bad and will disappear in the future... the sooner the better.

Comment: @Nate C-K - Response I am getting is, Response from PHP : User Found (next line)<!--Hosting24 Analytic Code--> (new line) <script type="text/javascript" src="http://states.hosting24.com/count.php"></script> (new line) <!--End Of Analytic Code-->

Comment: Also can you please tell me wat changes should I make in order to avoid name clashes for variable "response" ? Thank you

Comment: @Nate C-K- Could you identify why it is executing only else part ?

Comment: @xtré- Response I am getting is, Response from PHP : User Found (next line)<!--Hosting24 Analytic Code--> (new line) <script type="text/javascript" src="states.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>; (new line) <!--End Of Analytic Code-->

Comment: It looks like you are getting a bunch of text back from that HTTP request, and you are comparing it to the string "User Found". Only the beginning of the HTTP response matches. Maybe what you really want to be doing is testing if the response **starts** with that string? As for the variables, see my advice above: use a standard prefix like "\_" or "\m_" for instance variables. (You should also make them private unless you have a reason not to.)

Comment: @Nate-C-K- Thanks for your reply. I read your advice regarding using prefix like"_" or"\m" for instance variable but could not apply it in my code. Can you please tell me wat changes should I do to apply it in my code ?

Comment: @Nate C-K- I did few changes mentioned and now it is working correctly. Thank you so much for putting so much effort and helping me out.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your advises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing complex going on here; your response is clearly just not saying "User Found"; so you should check that thoroughly.

Just attach your debugger, set a breakpoint at that line, and see what the response actually says in this case.  It should be quite obvious what's amiss when you can pause there and step through/view the state of the various variables.

Alternately, you need to post the function that generates the response so we can see what it would return given your input.  There isn't enough information here for us to fully diagnose the issue currently.

Comment: @w00te- The response generating file is my check.php file. Plese check the updated question. thank you

Comment: @user3399423 - Well, you just said in a comment above that you're getting more than just "User Found" back.  For now, you can change .equalsIgnoreCase to .startsWith and it should work; but that's not a real or robust solution.  You should determine what is adding the extra text and stop it all-together, or build a more specific tag to search for in the response.

Comment: @w00te- I did the changes and its working correctly now. Thank you so much for ur help and advice.